# Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'. > Could not find com.github.adrielcafe:ffmpeg-android-java:2a627f6ecd

Tags: java, android, flutter, gradle

### Here is my console.

I can't get `com.github.adrielcafe:ffmpeg-android-java:2a627f6ecd`.Is it my fault?

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.github.adrielcafe:ffmpeg-android-java:2a627f6ecd.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/adrielcafe/ffmpeg-android-java/2a627f6ecd/ffmpeg-android-java-2a627f6ecd.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/adrielcafe/ffmpeg-android-java/2a627f6ecd/ffmpeg-android-java-2a627f6ecd.pom
       - http://download.flutter.io/com/github/adrielcafe/ffmpeg-android-java/2a627f6ecd/ffmpeg-android-java-2a627f6ecd.pom
       - http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/groups/public/com/github/adrielcafe/ffmpeg-android-java/2a627f6ecd/ffmpeg-android-java-2a627f6ecd.pom
       - http://sczpkj.f3322.net:8082/artifactory/android/com/github/adrielcafe/ffmpeg-android-java/2a627f6ecd/ffmpeg-android-java-2a627f6ecd.pom
       - https://storage.flutter-io.cn/download.flutter.io/com/github/adrielcafe/ffmpeg-android-java/2a627f6ecd/ffmpeg-android-java-2a627f6ecd.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/adrielcafe/ffmpeg-android-java/2a627f6ecd/ffmpeg-android-java-2a627f6ecd.pom
       - https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/google/com/github/adrielcafe/ffmpeg-android-java/2a627f6ecd/ffmpeg-android-java-2a627f6ecd.pom
       - https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/public/com/github/adrielcafe/ffmpeg-android-java/2a627f6ecd/ffmpeg-android-java-2a627f6ecd.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/com/github/adrielcafe/ffmpeg-android-java/2a627f6ecd/ffmpeg-android-java-2a627f6ecd.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > project :flutter_plugin_record > com.github.adrielcafe:AndroidAudioConverter:0.0.8

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

### Here is my android\build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "http://download.flutter.io" }
        maven {url 'http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/groups/public/'}
    }

    dependencies {
        // classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
//         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.20"


    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "http://download.flutter.io" }
        maven {url 'http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/groups/public/'}
//        maven {
//            url 'http://download.flutter.io'
//        }
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete .idea folder inside your project and reboot your Android Studio